# Matplotlib mixed subplots with plot and pcolor(mesh) to have the same x axis length when colorbar is on

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am wondering if it is possible to have a subplot with a mixture of graphs drawn with plot() and figures drawn with pcolormesh() that would have the same x axis length.

I attached 2 images one when the pcolormesh() subplot does not have the colorbar drawn when the x axes are the same length 
[image]
and one that has the colorbar when the pcolormesh() subplot is shrunk so that it accommodates the colorbar. [image]

I would like to have the colorbar, but it should be extending the length of the whole plot and not shrink the subplot.

Is this possible without sub-classing any of the current classes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, it's possible!

What's happening is that a new axes is being created for the colorbar, and the space is being taken from the axes that `pcolormesh` is plotted in.  If you don't want this to happen, you can specify an axes object for the colorbar to go in.  Alternately, you could just use a horizontal colorbar.

At any rate, let's reproduce your problem with stand-alone data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1977)

# Generate some interesting-looking random data...
num = 200
grid = np.random.normal(0, 1, (20, num)).cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=0)
x = np.linspace(0, 360, num)
y1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, num).cumsum()
y2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, num).cumsum()

# Plot on three seperate axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True)
axes[0].plot(x, y1)
axes[1].plot(x, y2)
im = axes[2].imshow(grid, extent=[0, 360, 0, 20], aspect='auto')
fig.colorbar(im)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

A quick fix is to just use a horizontal colorbar:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1977)

# Generate some interesting-looking random data...
num = 200
grid = np.random.normal(0, 1, (20, num)).cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=0)
x = np.linspace(0, 360, num)
y1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, num).cumsum()
y2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, num).cumsum()

# Plot on three seperate axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True)
axes[0].plot(x, y1)
axes[1].plot(x, y2)
im = axes[2].imshow(grid, extent=[0, 360, 0, 20], aspect='auto')
fig.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Alternately, you can manually add another axes for the colorbar.  We'll also adjust things a bit to make more room.

(Side note: Don't use `tight_layout` after making the extra axes. We're no longer working with a nice grid of subplots once we add the additional one, so `tight_layout` will not work correctly.  It's safe to use it before, though you may want to modify the call to `subplots_adjust` in that case.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1977)

# Generate some interesting-looking random data...
num = 200
grid = np.random.normal(0, 1, (20, num)).cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=0)
x = np.linspace(0, 360, num)
y1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, num).cumsum()
y2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, num).cumsum()

# Plot on three seperate axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True)
axes[0].plot(x, y1)
axes[1].plot(x, y2)
im = axes[2].imshow(grid, extent=[0, 360, 0, 20], aspect='auto')

# Make some room for the colorbar
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.07, right=0.87)

# Add the colorbar outside...
box = axes[2].get_position()
pad, width = 0.02, 0.02
cax = fig.add_axes([box.xmax + pad, box.ymin, width, box.height])
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks works perfectly especially the last solution is useful for me. I came up with something similar before seeing your solution based on gridspec.GridSpec and tight_layout, but yours is simpler and looks better. As you mentioned I had trouble adjusting spaces with tight_layout.